Bow lemma with angles
First, let me recall the statement of the bow lemma.

Let $\gamma_1: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\gamma_2: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be two smooth unit-speed curves.
Assume $\gamma_1$ and its chord bound a convex figure, and $k_1(s) \geqslant k_2(s)$ for any $s$, where $k_i$ denotes the curvature of $\gamma_i$.
Then the chord of $\gamma_1$ cannot be longer than the chord of $\gamma_2$; that is,
$$|\gamma_1(b) - \gamma_1(a)| \leqslant |\gamma_2(b) - \gamma_2(a)|.$$

I needed the following extension of this lemma, which must be known, but I was not able to find it in the literature. The proof is not hard (and even funny), but I would prefer to have a reference.


Let $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ be as in the bow lemma.
Set $w_i = \gamma_i(b) - \gamma_i(a)$,
$\alpha_i = \measuredangle(\gamma_i'(a), w_i)$,
$\beta_i = \measuredangle(\gamma_i'(b), w_i)$.
Then $$\beta_1 \leqslant \tfrac{\pi}{2}\qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad\alpha_1 \geqslant \alpha_2.$$


Anton, I changed what I thought to be a typo, i.e. the fact that $\gamma_2$ is a plane curve: if I misread your text, please feel free to revert it.

@DanieleTampieri it was not a typo, but it is OK to reduce generality.
